# ASM space optimization: EAX vs EBX

Tags: assembly, x86, compiler-optimization, instruction-encoding

I'm working on an x86 assembly code golf puzzle. I'm assembling the source file using NASM:

```
nasm -f elf32 -O0 main.s
ld -m elf_i386 -s -O0 -o main main.o
```

Using `-O0`, all optimizations should be turned off. The goal is to reduce the size of the ELF binary.

While working on the "reference implementation" for the puzzle, I stumbled over a strange behavior. This is a reduced code sample:

```
section .text
    global _start        ; Must be declared for linker

_start:                  ; Entry point for linker

read_stdin:
    add    esp, 8        ; Ignore argc and argv[0] on stack
    pop    eax           ; Store pointer to 'argv[1]' into EAX
    mov    eax, [eax]    ; Dereference pointer
    and    eax, 0xff     ; We only want the least significant byte
    add    eax, -0x30    ; Subtract ascii offset

exit:
    mov    eax, 1        ; Syscall: sys_exit
    mov    ebx, 0        ; Exit code 0
    int    0x80          ; Invoke syscall
```

The binary is 264 bytes:

```
$ wc -c main
264 main
```

Now when I simply replace all occurrences of `eax` in the `read_stdin` section with `ebx`, `ecx` or `edx`, the binary gets larger:

```
$ wc -c main
268 main
```

When comparing the sizes of the object files, the difference is even larger (480 vs 496 bytes). What's special about the `eax` register that this happens? Is NASM doing some kind of optimization, even though `-O0` has been specified?

Comment: Did you take a look with a binary diff?

Comment: A few specific instruction combos can indeed be encoded shorter when EAX (or sometimes AX or AL) is the register used.

Comment: if you want to reduce the size, you should use `-Os` instead

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I'm the one creating the puzzle, so I want people to optimize the code themselves, and not rely on some automatic optimization :)

Comment: Note that with modern `ld`, you'll also want `-n` to not align sections to page boundaries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EAX is the accumulator register.  It has special one-byte opcodes for all nine basic operations (ADD, ADC, AND, CMP, OR, SBB, SUB, TEST, and XOR).  Also the MOV instruction has a one-byte opcode for moving data into the accumulator from a constant memory location.

[The Art of Picking Intel Registers](http://www.swansontec.com/sregisters.html)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I found a few useful related links: http://www.swansontec.com/sregisters.html http://www.swansontec.com/sintel.html http://www.mathemainzel.info/files/x86asmref.html#add

Comment: Updated to cite that, sorry.

Comment: @DaniloBargen: Strange that NASM `-O0` picks the `add eax, imm32` encoding for `add    eax, -0x30`.  That's still an optimization over `add r/m32, imm32`.  (But of course if you assemble normally, you'd get `add r/m32, imm8` even for EAX, because that's smaller still.)  Of course if you want to optimize by hand, you'd movzx load and/or `and al, 0x0f` if you want to assume the input is an ASCII 0..9 digit.  Anyway, unless you expect people solving this challenge to encode instructions manually, requiring `-O0` removes access to `r/m32, imm8` encodings.

Comment: Also related: [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981) for many tips about saving code-size through choice of registers, instruction, and their encodings.